# Thymeleaf update link

Tags: thymeleaf, href, crud

I want to create an update link for CRUD-update operations in Thymeleaf
In JSP it looks like this:

How it will look in Thymeleaf? I'll appreciate any hints, because I'm stuck on this for two days. I searched everywhere.

Comment: You didn't include the JSP code snippet. It is not clear what you're asking

Comment: I have resolved this issue. Problem was very simple, but I forgot I was using get method.  I wanted to send properties to get method using thymeleaf. Here is the code:  <td><a th:href="@{/customer/showFormForUpdate(customerId=${c.id})}">update</a></td>